# Why can't restart Filebeat on the client?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

When I restart filebeat on the client:

```
~$ sudo service filebeat restart
```

I get an error:

```
Restarting Sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
filebeat                                                        
2016/08/27 14:00:17.183511 transport.go:125: ERR SSL client failed to connect with: dial tcp my-ip:5044: i/o timeout
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

I used the tutorial on [ELK on digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04)  to setup

More info:

I am using port 5044, `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :5044` gives:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::5044                 :::*                    LISTEN      25618/java
```

Comment: Are you sure you configured your logstash correctly? I myself use graylog, in which we have to configure input (one that receive messages from filebeat).

Comment: I'm not sure, that is why I am asking the question.

Comment: This is a certificate generation issue on the server.